# Implementation of myspace and linkedin in iphone

Tags: iphone

I want to implement LinkedIn and Myspace in iphone application. I mean I want to change status of both using my app. Is there any API available to access both? I tried OAuth API but its not working only working for Twitter..

Thanks,
in Advance.

Comment: OAuth is just a way to get authenticated and access the APIs of a web service. It's not the LinkedIn or MySpace API.

Answer (score 0):

Both LinkedIn and Myspace both have an API, and both support OAuth.  You can find more infomation through their respective developer network sites:

- [LinkedIn Developer Network](http://developer.linkedin.com) - [LinkedIn OAuth](http://developer.linkedin.com/docs/DOC-1008)
- [Myspace Developer Network](http://developer.myspace.com) - [MySpace OAuth](http://wiki.developer.myspace.com/index.php?title=OAuth_Overview)

---

To update status:

- LinkedIn: [Post Network Update](http://developer.linkedin.com/docs/DOC-1009)
- MySpace: [Status_and_Mood_API - Updating_a_Status_and_Mood](http://wiki.developer.myspace.com/index.php?title=Status_and_Mood_API#Updating_a_Status_and_Mood)

Comment: Thanks for this but I have already used this and integrated with api. But I want to update my status of both social sites through my app. if you have code or link for that, pls guide me..... Thaks..

Comment: @user333242 It's all in the API docs - have a look through, they're fairly good, they really want people to develop against these APIs.  I've added direct links to sections that might help you.