# how to integrate myspace into my iPhone App 

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ios4, myspace

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Implementation of myspace and linkedin in iphone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3987282/implementation-of-myspace-and-linkedin-in-iphone)

I am new to iPhone technology

I am using API in JSON. I need to integrate myspace into my app

How can it be done?

Answer (score 1):

Try this: http://code.google.com/p/myspaceid-iphone-sdk/